# CSS RGBA Transparency in Safari behaves different. How could I fix it?

Tags: css, safari, background, transparency, opacity

My code works well in every browser, the text keeps its white opaque color on top of the semi-transparent background `(background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0,.4))`. However, in Safari, the background transparency value is different (much lighter) and the text is also affected by the transparency and it doesn't keep its full color. I tried changing the font color `(color: #fff;)` to the H2 and p only, but it didn't work. I've spent tons of hours trying to fix this, but I couldn't find a solution. Any idea how to fix it?

Please, take a look in Chrome and also in Safari. 
Thank you for your help!!

This is the website I am working on: http://www.mattresszombie.com

This is my html code:

```css
#prueba-block1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0,.4);
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-bottom: 110px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  z-index: -7;
}

#prueba-block1 h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-stretch: expanded; 
}

#prueba-block1 p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<div id="prueba-block1">
  <h2>We are going to make mattress shopping simple!</h2>
  <p>This is an informational website to provide the facts about mattresses.</p>
  <p>We have no affiliation with any manufacturer, any retailer, any website, nor any brand.</p>
  <p><strong>Let's get started!</strong></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tis not about color transparency, it's all about `z-index`

Please set

`z-index:1` to `#fixed`
`z-index:-1` to `#container`

and remove `z-index: -7` from `#prueba-block1`